# How to use tornado.httpclient.AynscHTTPClient to fetch a page which need login?

Tags: unit-testing, tornado

I'm write a litter web app with tornado. And I am write the unittest use the tornado.httpclient.AynscHttpClient to test the index page,but the index page need user to be login. I rewrite the get_current_user need the user in the db, the login page has a xsrf_input, so I can't fetch the login page with post.

I find the tornaod.httpClient.HTTPRequest has a paramter auth_username and auth_password. but it doesnot work. I donot what it mean. but I'm strap now.

Hope for you help

Answer (score 0):

Set xsrf_cookies=False.
Try it again。